# Tailwind Apply equivalent for PrimeFlex

Tags: tailwind-css, primeflex

I'm using PrimeFlex (with PrimeVue) and I'd like to know if there is a way to apply PrimeFlex classes in the CSS rather than in the template.
I know that in tailwind you can use the `@apply` like explained in [the tailwind doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply).

The purpose here is to create reusable classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I just found out the answer in the docs. I don't know why I didn't saw this before but I prefer to put there the answer rather than deleting my question.

You can simply use `@include styleclass("the-classes-as-string")` as it's explained [in the docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/setup) in the Reuse Classes section.